# Azure Logic App / Create CSV File in Blob : need to wait until the blob is complete

Tags: azure, csv, azure-logic-apps, synchronous, azure-blob-storage

I have a problem synchronizing the creation of a blob and consumption by API of this blob.

First, I use ***Create Blob*** to put a .csv file on a blob.
Then, pipe a component ***HTTP*** to send this file thanks a proxy API from the blob storage to a remote application : MFT, which I encapsulated the call of its API in a proxy API.

Unfortunatly, the component ***Create Blob*** ends before the file is actually created on the blob storage. After a duration of 1 second, the API call don't find the file on the blob storage.

**My question :** How to configure the component ***Create Blob*** to wait until the file creation is complete on the blob storage ?

I have try to use synchronous/asynchronous parameter, but in vain.

As a work around, I intend to use a combination of ***Until*** + ***Get Blob*** to check if the file exist on the blob storage before calling the API.

Thanks,

**Create Blob code :**

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "body": "@outputs('Compose')",
        "path": "/datasets/default/files",
        "queries": {
            "folderPath": "/folder-export",
            "name": "@{concat('EXPORT_DATA_',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd'),'.csv')}",
            "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
        },
        "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
    },
    "runtimeConfiguration": {
        "contentTransfer": {
            "transferMode": "Chunked"
        }
    },
    "limit": {
        "timeout": "PT10M"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Guillaume, may I know if your "Create Blob" is in a "For each" action ? Could you please share some more details of your logic(such as the screenshot) ?

Comment: Hi Hury, Unfortunately, under 10 contributions, I can't share screenshot.

Comment: Finally, I choose to use Share File (since my Logic Apps generate flat file), and solve the problem using the component "Create File". Then I modify my proxy API to connect to Azure Storage Share File insteed of Blob Contaier. Thise way, the file is instantly available on the Share File, and can be consumed by my proxy API. Thanks Hury for your assistance. FI, the "Create Blob" wasn't in a "For each" loop.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that your issue was solved, could you please put your solution in the answer area ? It may help other people, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To help more people who are at risk of experiencing this problem, I summarize the solution here(according to the solution provided by Guillaume in the comments):

To replace the "Create blob" action, we can use Azure File share, we can find how to create it by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share) tutorial. In azure logic app, we can use "create file" action.

[image]

We can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurefile/#create-file) page for "create file" action.